# Stress Not! - A North Daniels' Puzzle

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge, story

*Beep, beep, beep, beep...*

No, this was not the sound of D.S.I North Daniels playing miniature cricket on his phone, although that would be a preferable situation to the one he is in now.

Unfortunately, EOD Operator classes were not part of police training, and watching all those Die Hard movies didn't yield any useful information applicable to the current situation.

There was a **bomb** in his house

It was like a spherical white globe and was very, very small. It really did not fit the Bohemian style of his Islington studio apartment. What's more, the aggressor took the trouble to bolt the thing to the floor, which not only made it impossible to move, but also ruined the tiles he'd laid only yesterday. Also, being on the fifteenth floor, it's unlikely any help would reach him very quickly, since the lift was broken **again**, and the telephone was down due to the riots in the telecommunications sector

Luckily for him, *and I'm really scraping the bottom of the barrel here*, the aggressor had left some "handy hints" to help disarm the bomb. The bomb itself had a keyboard on top, with a large red button in the middle. A note on the side said:

[image: Note]

***Text Copy***

```
Hello, bungling idiot,
    
As you now know, otherwise I'd seriously consult a doctor, there is a bomb in your apartment, and MY GOSH did it take AGES to haul this thing up all FIFTEEN flights of stairs!
    
This keyboard you see is your key to safety (or hopefully your demise), as entering the correct password and pressing the red button will disarm the bomb. If you fail to do so after ONE HOUR, bye-bye!
    
However, since wrenching this infernal thing up to your apartment BROKE A NAIL, you'll only get one shot at disarming the bomb
    
Anyway, here are the clues:

    An order of ten
    An American car model
    A German sausage (sort of)
    A borderline Gemini writer

Hope I do not see you soon,

G.H
```

As Daniels slumped on his Chesterfield sofa, gazing at the note, his mind wandered away, reflecting on the last five years of police service, hoping something would be useful, but nothing came. Sure, that year abroad taking flying lessons was amazing, and curling up in the evenings in front of the TV watching a documentary about George the Third was magical...

"*Whoops, off topic*" said Daniels, as he leapt up and paced nervously up and down the room, mulling over the four clues in his head.

"*Maybe they represent something...*"

"*Maybe they are linked somehow...*"

"*Maybe my experiences will help...*"

"*Maybe my whole life is connected with this...*"

No, it was hopeless, he had to run and get some help, without hurting his ankle running down the stairs. So, he hurtled towards the door, grabbed the ebony door knob, and...

"*Wait a moment...*"

After standing still for almost a minute, North rushed towards the bomb, typed in the answer, and slammed the red button....

Suddenly, he was greeted by one of his own terrible songs emanating from the bomb about people's limbs being swapped. He **HATED** that song...

---

What was the password?

---

***Hints***

> 1. North was on the right track when he pondered the four existential questions, although they do not map onto the four clues left by "G.H"

> 2. Just for fun, North sent G.H this message:
> `To my dearest G.H`
> `As you now probably know, I survived your little scheme. Why didn't your clues include:`
> `An eagle`
> `An occurrence without method or decision`
> `An Eric Jacobson muppet`
> `Say hello to Jelia for me - I haven't been to the prison for years! Her poetry is remarkable!`
> `Lots of love`
> `North`

> 3. Of the seven clues, at least three are quite specific. Try listing all possibilities of them down, and see if you spot anything

> 4. XP is valuable, especially when written down

***MEGA HINTS***

> 1. The console North is looking at has a screen saying "Enter the answer", a numerical keypad, and a big red button that says "ENTER":
> [image: Interface]

> 2. You are looking for (To reserve)s

Comment: Not sure if this relevant, but it bothers me: rot13(Vs lbh'er ba gur svsgrragu sybbe, fubhyq or abg bayl unir unq gb tb hc sbhegrra syvtugf bs fgnvef?)

Comment: @WeckarE. Just a question to puzzling. Why do many users give something in rot13?

Comment: @math To prevent spoilers for people just scrolling. Then again, I'm sure some people here have by now become fluent at reading rot13...

Comment: @WeckarE. Not me. I need a decoder ;-)

Comment: @WeckarE.  Everything in the clue points to this taking place in rot13(Ratynaq, juvpu ahzore Z, 1, 2, rgp.)

Comment: Also @WeckarE, your not on the right lines - try focusing firstly on the four clues (one of them is very specific). I'll add a hint tomorrow

Comment: @WeckarE, in the UK, buildings start on the Ground Floor, then 1st, 2nd...

Comment: Hint number 2 is out